# Tell whether an image shows mainly ONE person (not zero or several persons)

Tags: gratis, image-recognition

I have a [million images](http://tinyurl.com/y9drectr) that are supposed to **each show one person**.

**Problem**: A few bogus images show **nobody**. A few other bogus images show **several people** without it being clear who the real subject is.

**Question**: Is there a tool or library or web service that can tell me whether an image shows mainly one person?

## Examples of "good" pictures:

[image]

Note the before-last image: It contains other persons, but it is clear to a *human eye* who the main topic of the image is. But solutions that are not that smart are OK too.

Also note the engraving of a person on a horse: While the person's face and body are barely visible, a human easily understands that the image represents a person. False positives are excusable here, but a tool that understands that would be wonderful.

## Examples of "bad" pictures:

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

*Any operating system, any technology.*